# How to remove disk from running Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I got a 6 Node Hadoop cluster with HDP 2.3 installed.

Node consist 2 drive one is of 50 TB and other is of 2 TB, now the disk with 2 TB is full. But i want to remove this disk from all node and only wanna use 50 TB disk for Hadoop.

**Question**

Can i safely remove data disk without causing missing/corrupt blocks on Cluster.

**Update**

output of mount command is below

```
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
/tmp on /tmp type none (rw,bind)
/var/tmp on /var/tmp type none (rw,bind)
/home on /home type none (rw,bind)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
/dev/sdc1 on /data1 type xfs (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /data type xfs (rw)
```

And value for property dfs.datanode.data.dir is */data/hadoop/hdfs/data,/data1/hadoop/hdfs/data*

Comment: Depends. Can you post the output of "mount" on your nodes, and what is the value for dfs.datanode.data.dir hadoop variable?

Comment: @facha updated the question with required info.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take the 2 TB drive as the NameNode metadata may get corrupt. Namenode will be waiting for the block report from this node and will near leave safemode if the data blocks in the form of block reports are not reported.

One workaround can be you can copy all the data into 50 TB drive and format the Namenode. You cannot perform this operation on the cases where data is sensitive.

Comment: That i know but is there a way that was my question.

Comment: Did you add datanodes using hosts include file? if yes you can decommission the 2TB drive without any loss of data.